# One domain but two MX records for two group of accounts

Tags: mx-record

Here is what I want to try:
**One Domain**: mydomain.com;
**Two MX Records**: one is MX1 (Exchange), the other one is MX2 (Google Apps)
**Two group of accounts**: Teacher accounts are in Exchange; Student accounts are in Google Apps. Exchange and Google Apps don't have any overlap accounts.

Emails sent to teacher-1@mydomain.com go to MX1 and emails sent to student-1@mydomian.com go to MX2.

Is this workable? Thanks much!

Comment: You'll need to setup and configure a shared SMTP namespace. This is how to do it from the Exchange side of things (assuming Exchange Server 2010) - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676395(v=exchg.141).aspx

Comment: @joeqwerty +1 for shared namespace, that can and will simplify things

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, MX records don't have a concept of account types.

You have three basic options to accomplish this.

1. use sub domains. You would setup `student.mydomain.com` and `staff.mydomain.com` and point the MX records as appropriate for those setups.
2. Put a relay server in between your two mail back-ends and have it hide the above configuration so you would have a virtual address that points to staff_person@mydomain.com and the relay knows to send that to your exchange environment as well as having a student_person@mydomain.com and the relay knows to send that to google.
3. Just use one mail system for both staff and students.